# Sending XML Soap request using Python requests.post()

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, python-requests

I'm sure I'm doing this all sorts of wrong as I don't know anything about Xml or SOAP, but I'm trying to send send SOAP requests using Python requests.post(). I figured I could just pass the body as plain text. If I use `data=body` I get a decoding error saying Latin-1 can't be used, even though I thought I put decoding for `utf-8`. If I use `params=body` the request is successful, but it says I have an invalid Root element. How would I go about parsing the following xml document? I'm simply trying to pass the Authentication process per these instructions:
https://developer.stamps.com/developer/docs/swsimv71.html#authentication

The xml element Tree is here: 
https://swsim.testing.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv71.asmx?wsdl

I used the following code to attempt a Post request to send my Credentials for authentications. If you could let me know where and how badly I'm screwing up this request, I would appreciate it.

```
url = "https://swsim.testing.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv71.asmx"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Crosscheck Networks SOAPSonar',
    'content-type': 'text/xml',
    'charset': 'utf-8'
}

body = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:tns=“http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2018/03/swsim/swsimv71”
>

    <soap:Body>

        <AuthenticateUser>

            <tns:Credentials>

                <IntegrationsID>
                    ID
                </IntegrationsID>

                <Username>
                    USERNAME
                </Username>

                <Password>
                    PASSWORD
                </Password>

            </tns:Credentials>

        </AuthenticateUser>

    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

"""

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=body)
print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you, my friend!

```
    import requests

    request = '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Requ>
    <GivenName>Özdemam</GivenName>
    <FamilyNameGrünzl</FamilyName>
    </Requ>
    '''.encode('utf-8')
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml': 'charset=utf-8'}
    req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://192.168.1.5:8888/api',
                   headers=headers,
                   data=request)

    prepped_requ = req.prepare()
    s = requests.Session()
    http_response = s.send(prepped_requ)
    print http_response
```

Comment: @Sidonai: I reluctantly voted to approve your edit. Generally it is best to offer such (even mildly) substantive corrections by leaving a Comment for the original poster.

Comment: @hardmath I made the correction because the code was not executable, it wasn't just a substantive correction, or what do you mean with that?

Comment: @Sidonai: A substantive change is one that changes the post in a significant way, as opposed to "cosmetic changes" which affect the appearance (typos, formatting, etc.) without affecting the nature of a post.  So again, for substantive changes it is better to offer them first to the original poster to approve.

Comment: This is a Post request example, not a SOAP request.. am I wrong?

Comment: For anyone coming here and also wondering about @cyclical's question - SOAP requests are made via HTTP POST